# Migration from OAuth1 3L to OAuth2:

Tags: google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

I'm trying to migrate existing OAuth1.0 3L tokens to OAuth2.0 for a web app.
I am following the instructions at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref
Despite all my best efforts, I keep getting this response:
"Invalid authorization header."

To create the Authorization header, I use Google's Java client library 1.0, the same I use in the application to talk to google calendar.
I am testing with an access token. token secret, consumer key and consumer secret that work without problem (i.e. I can use these credentials to make calls to Google Calendar, etc).

This is the code I use:

```
    OAuthParameters oauthParameters = new OAuthParameters();
    oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey("www.mywebsite.com"); // this is the same consumer key used by my app normally, without problem. mywebsite is an example, the real name is different
    oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXXXX");
    oauthParameters.setOAuthToken("YYYYY");
    oauthParameters.setOAuthTokenSecret("ZZZZZZ");

    OAuthHmacSha1Signer signer = new OAuthHmacSha1Signer();
    OAuthHelper oauthHelper = new GoogleOAuthHelper(signer);
    String requestUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
    String header = oauthHelper.getAuthorizationHeader(requestUrl, "POST", oauthParameters);
    String payload = "grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Amigration%3Aoauth1&client_id="+clientId+"&client_secret="+clientSecret;

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(requestUrl);
    httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", header);
    httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(payload.getBytes()));
    String response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, new BasicResponseHandler());
```

and this is the wire trace produced by HttpClient:

```
>> "POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
>> "Authorization: OAuth realm="", oauth_signature="ixVbjINI6pgPU2RqXGiQRbPGY%3D", oauth_nonce="486642280771700", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key="www.mywebsite.com", oauth_token="YYYYY", oauth_timestamp="1395127834"[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded[\r][\n]"
>> "Content-Length: 193[\r][\n]"
>> "Host: accounts.google.com[\r][\n]"
>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
>> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.2 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
>> "[\r][\n]"
>> "grant_type=urn%ietf%params%oauth%grant-type%migration%oauth1&client_id=12345&client_secret=ABCDE"
<< "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"
<< "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate[\r][\n]"
<< "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
<< "Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "Date: Tue, 18 Mar 2014 07:30:39 GMT[\r][\n]"
<< "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
<< "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
<< "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN[\r][\n]"
<< "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]"
<< "Server: GSE[\r][\n]"
<< "Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic[\r][\n]"
<< "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"
<< "5a[\r][\n]"
<< "{[\n]"
<< "  "error" : "invalid_request",[\n]"
<< "  "error_description" : "Invalid authorization header."[\n]"
<< "}"
<< "[\r][\n]"
<< "0[\r][\n]"
<< "[\r][\n]"
```

where 12345 and ABCDE are obviously placeholders for the real OAuth2 app credentials.

I have double and triple checked that all the parameters set in OAuthParameters are the same used by the normal code that is currently working using OAuth1 (even using a step-by-step debugger to verify the values at the time the signature is calculated by OAuthHmacSha1Signer.getSignature()).

I looked at the Authorization header in HTTP requests sent by the current Google Client APIs that use OAuth1 (and that work fine), and apart obviously from signature, nonce and timestamp they look identical to the one sent by this migration call.

I even tried a test migration request , which failed, then used a debugger to run the old code and inject method, URL, nonce and timestamp used by the migration call, and the signature calculated by the old code was identical, given identical params.

Any clues of why the Authorization header is still reported as invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following up with SimonM, it turns out that the issue was related to the base string used to sign the migration request.

When constructing a base string to sign your migration requests, make sure that the string uses a **POST** method (rather than GET as it is the case when accessing many Google APIs) and that it **contains all relevant migration parameters** as per the [migration documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref#SigningOAuth).

As per [OAuth1 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4.1), a valid base string for a migration request should look like:

POST&https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:migration:oauth1&oauth_consumer_key=YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY&oauth_nonce=NONCE&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1396414006&oauth_token=THE_TOKEN_TO_MIGRATE

Note that, for readability purpose, the above is the decoded version of the base string (check out the [OAuth1 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4.1) for more examples).

Comment: can you plz post a link to the source code that you used? because i'm getting the same error tough i'm constructing the string using POST

Answer (score 1):

When generating the base string you will need to ensure that each individual parameter is URL encoded before constructing the base string.

As per the oAuth documentation to [sign OAuth 1.0 requests](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref#SigningOAuth) the base string is made up of 3 components

- The HTTP request method
- The base URL the request is being sent to
- A normalized string of the parameters in the request

When constructing the base string you need to do the following

- Ensure HTTP request method is POST
- URL encode the base URL
- Ensure the three POST body parameters [client_id, client_secret, grant_type] are included in the normalized request parameters
- Ensure each parameter is individually URL encoded and then URL encode  the complete normalized request parameters string. So in effect, some of the paramters are double URL encoded. This double URL encoding is mentioned in [Using OAuth with the Google Data APIs#Signing Requests](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/oauth#Signing) for the oauth_token

Only after doing all these steps did I get the migration request to work and I received a valid refresh_token

Below is a sample base string

```
POST&https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fo%2Foauth2%2Ftoken&client_id%3Dxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com%26client_secret%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxx%26grant_type%3Durn%253Aietf%253Aparams%253Aoauth%253Agrant-type%253Amigration%253Aoauth1%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dxxxxxxxxx%26oauth_nonce%3D4106001%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1400779530%26oauth_token%3D1%252FkklP1YPy_AULt7j_tttttt_tterwerkj_dfj45dflk
```

Answer (score 0):

The auth header in OAuth2 is a bearer token. It should look something like

```
Authorization: Bearer 0b79bab50daca910b000d4f1a2b675d604257e42
```

Comment: The tutorial at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref explicitly says the authorization header must use OAuth 1.0. After all, we start with OAuth 1.0 credentials. It explicitly shows what the Auth header should look like, and it's Authorization: OAuth

Comment: my mistake. I thought you had completed the migration step. The grant type in your question looks odd. Is that what was sent, or was it scrambled by the SO editor?

Comment: good spotting, no it's actually
grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Amigration%3Aoauth1 as per the tutorial's example. Form encoded.

But I'm not sure the issue lies in the request payload... the error message is "Invalid authorization header" so I assume it's more about that header? But you never know...