# Issue during migration from Google OAuth 1.0 to OAuth 2.0

Tags: google-oauth

I have to migrate from Google OAuth 1.0 to OAuth 2.0.
I just have wrote a small request in Chrome Rest Client:

**POST**: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

**Headers**: Authorization: OAuth realm="", oauth_signature="PU3W5uRL0eAyEi", oauth_nonce="1396865138306881000", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key="XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com", oauth_token="YYYYY", oauth_timestamp="1396865138", Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

**Payload**: grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:migration:oauth1&client_id=ZZZZZ.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=SSSSS

For that I receive an error message: 
Status: 400 Bad Request

"{
error: "invalid_request"
error_description: "Invalid authorization header."
}"

The problem could be that I try to migrate from one Project in Google Developers Console to another. 
Could that really be a problem?

The reason that I moved to another project is because I cannot create OAuth 2.0 Client ID in the original Project. I receive the following error message:

"*You can not create OAuth 2.0 client ID because this project already contains an Oauth 1.0 client ID.*"

Please suggest.

Thank you,
E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496473/migration-from-oauth1-3l-to-oauth2/22898397#22898397), when constructing the base string to sign your migration requests, please make sure that the string uses a **POST method** and that it **contains all relevant migration parameters** as per the migration documentation.

As per [OAuth1 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4.1), a valid base string for a migration request should look like:

POST&https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:migration:oauth1&oauth_consumer_key=YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY&oauth_nonce=NONCE&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1396414006&oauth_token=THE_TOKEN_TO_MIGRATE

Note that, for readability purpose, the above is the decoded version of the base string (check out the [OAuth1 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4.1) for more examples).

Hope that helps, Miguel.

Comment: Hi Miguel! Could you please elaborate what do you mean by "base string"? Or, what would be more helpful, what is wrong with the Java code in the post you mentioned above. Thank you. E

Comment: Check out Google documentation on signing OAuth1 requests: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref#SigningOAuth

The error you are getting means that the "oauth_signature" value in your request is wrong. Such value is obtained by signing the base string (mentioned in the documentation). Thus, a wrong base string leads to a wrong signature and ultimately an invalid request.

Comment: Hi Miguel, I have created a signature based on the correct base string. However, the error message is the same. What else should I check? Thank you. E

Answer (score 0):

When generating the base string you will need to ensure that each individual parameter is URL encoded before constructing the base string.

As per the oAuth documentation to [sign OAuth 1.0 requests](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref#SigningOAuth) the base string is made up of 3 components

- The HTTP request method
- The base URL the request is being sent to
- A normalized string of the parameters in the request

When constructing the base string you need to do the following

- Ensure HTTP request method is POST
- URL encode the base URL
- Ensure the three POST body parameters [client_id, client_secret, grant_type] are included in the normalized request parameters
- Ensure each parameter is individually URL encoded and then URL encode  the complete normalized request parameters string. So in effect, some of the paramters are double URL encoded. This double URL encoding is mentioned in [Using OAuth with the Google Data APIs#Signing Requests](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/oauth#Signing) for the oauth_token

Only after doing all these steps did I get the migration request to work and I received a valid refresh_token

Below is a sample base string

```
POST&https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fo%2Foauth2%2Ftoken&client_id%3Dxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com%26client_secret%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxx%26grant_type%3Durn%253Aietf%253Aparams%253Aoauth%253Agrant-type%253Amigration%253Aoauth1%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dxxxxxxxxx%26oauth_nonce%3D4106001%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1400779530%26oauth_token%3D1%252FkklP1YPy_AULt7j_tttttt_tterwerkj_dfj45dflk
```