# Migrating from OAuth2.1 to OAuth2.0

Tags: java, gwt, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have a GWT web application. I have big table with Google tokens and token secrets.
I want to move to OAuth2.0 without reauthenticating the users. I have tried the following in Java tests

```
  String url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    String generatedString = Utils.generateRandomString(10);
    String key = new Date().getTime() + "";

    // add header
    post.setHeader("Host", "accounts.google.com");
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    post.setHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " +
            "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + CONSUMER_KEY + "\"," +
            "oauth_token=\"" + token + "\"," +
            "oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\"" +
            "timestamp=\"" + key +  "\"," +
            "oauth_nonce=\"" + generatedString + "\"," +
            "oauth_signature=\"" + calculateRFC2104HMAC(key, generatedString) + "\"," +
            "oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\"");

    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:migration:oauth1"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", CONSUMER_KEY));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", CONSUMER_SECRET));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_consumer_key", CONSUMER_KEY));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_consumer_secret", CONSUMER_SECRET));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_timestamp", "" + new Date().getTime()));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_token", token));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_token_secret", token));

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    System.out.println("Sending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + post.getEntity());
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line;

    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }

    System.out.println(result.toString());
```

But I still can't get any adequate response. I get only:

#### Response Code : 400 
{  
"error" : "invalid_request",  "error_description" : "Invalid authorization header."
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to generate a valid oauth_signature as per the [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref#SigningOAuth)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23813363/470393) for some useful tips when generating the base string

The POST body should only contain 3 params as follows

```
grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Amigration%3Aoauth1&
client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret=xxxxxxxxxx
```