# Google OAuth1 migration to OAuth2

Tags: migration, google-oauth

Please don't confuse this question with this one: [Migration from OAuth1 3L to OAuth2:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496473/migration-from-oauth1-3l-to-oauth2)

I have been migrating my system users from google OAuth1 to OAuth2 as [specified here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref#migration).

The usual problem with this migrations is the building of the base_string which was a problem for me before asking this question. After fixing the base_string build up I did migrate 95% of my users but a small amount of users kept returning a 400 error:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "Invalid authorization header."
}
```

Here are the most important fields to check on:

base_string:
`POST&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Foauth2%2Fv3%2Ftoken&client_id%3DXXX%26client_secret%3DXXX%26grant_type%3Durn%253Aietf%253Aparams%253Aoauth%253Agrant-type%253Amigration%253Aoauth1%26oauth_consumer_key%3DXXX%26oauth_nonce%3D178143337915967474871427127026%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1427127026%26oauth_token%3D1%XXX`

URL: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token`

I have to say, this users do work with OAuth1 at the moment so they are fully valid connections. An invalid/expired connection returns me this 500 error:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_token",
  "error_description": "Either the token is invalid or we could not decode it."
}
```

Comment: Hello, my name is Miguel and I work in Google's OAuth team. In order to figure out what is wrong with the signature in your request I will need further information. Please contact me at gueles at google dot com. Once we figure out what the problem was, I will post the solution in this thread.

Comment: did you solve this problem? i have same problem :(

Comment: Not really, after a lot of back and forth with Miguel we couldn't find the issue, I just deactivated those user accounts and made them re-connect again (luckily there were not as many users with this issue for me)